# Dropdown default select value

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a Dropdown control where I am binding the data, after bind I am putting the select statement.  Even though the index is kept to 0 always select comes last like this:

Current output:

```
india
Auz
US
--select--
```

Required output:

```
--select--
india
AUZ
US
```

My Code

```
ddlcounty.DataSource = dtNew;
ddlcounty.DataTextField = "Weight";
ddlcounty.DataValueField = "Weight";
ddlcounty.DataBind();

ddlcounty.Items.Add("--Select--");
ddlcounty.SelectedValue = "0";
```

What is the change required here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your binding first.

When you get to the part where you are adding your default condition, you're actually adding to the end of the list.

Instead of :-

```
ddlcounty.Items.Add("--Select--");
```

Do :-

```
ddlcounty.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--"));
```

This will insert your default option as the first element of **Items**.

**Announced edit**

You won't need :-

```
ddlcounty.SelectedValue = 0;
```

.. as if you don't explicitly specify, the first item in a drop down list is automatically selected.

If, however, you want to be explicit about it, you can do the following:-

```
ddlcounty.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--","0"));
ddlcounty.SelectedValue = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try below way:

Just set `AppendDataBoundItems` to true and Insert a `ListItem` as selected, and 'ClearSelection' before selecting item as below.

```
ddlcounty.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddlcounty.DataSource = dtNew;
ddlcounty.DataTextField = "Weight";
ddlcounty.DataValueField = "Weight";
ddlcounty.DataBind();

ddlcounty.ClearSelection();
ddlcounty.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--", Selected = true });
ddlcounty.SelectedValue = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare the "select one" ListItem declaratively in your aspx page like so

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUIC" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="200px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Weight") %>' DataTextField="Weight" DataValueField="Weight" >
     <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
 /asp:DropDownList>
```

But your `AppendDataBoundItems` would have to be set to `true`

And you could still perform your databinding on the backend.